# service worker is not in navigator

Tags: javascript, web, firefox

I am trying to add push notifications to my app to do this I am using service workers.
for me everything works correctly on google chrome and Firefox but for my friend it says that `navigetor.serviceWorker` is `undefined`. he is using Firefox 94.0.2 (64-bit) that should support it according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/serviceWorker)

the site http protocol is https and `window.isSecureContext` is `true`

I don't know what is the problem all I see about it is the browser support and the secure window things but all of those are ok.

ill be glad if you will be able to help me :)